# Unity - using Colliders with custom objects

Tags: unity, meshcollider

Hi so I'm quite new to Unity and currently experiencing issues with colliders, a quick summary of what I have.

Player >

```
Object = Capsule ( Directly created through Unity )
Components = CharacterController, CapsuleCollider & a PlayerController script
```

Basic Tile >

```
Object = Rectangle ( Imported from blender )
Components = BoxCollider
```

this combination works well, no issues. However when I get to slightly more complex objects, such as elevated terrain I can't apply a `box collider` because the surface isn't flat. So my next thought was to add a `Mesh Collider` but unfortunately it doesn't seem to do anything effective ( my player falls through ) I don't know whether that's because `Mesh Colliders` are only relevant to `RigidBodies`? Unfortunately though I can't switch from a `CharacterController` to a `RigidBody`.

So I'm not sure what to do, maybe `MeshColliders` are reponsive to a `CharacterController` and my settings aren't adjusted correctly?

Comment: Have you marked the mesh collider component as convex? Mesh Colliders that aren't marked convex will only work for Meshes that are marked as static (top right of the inspector window)

Comment: To be more precise: static Mesh Colliders that are not convex will not collide with other *Mesh* colliders, but can still collide with dynamic capsules. It's possible that your capsule was spawned inside the convex region instead of outside of it. Can you show us a screenshot so we can understand the shape of object you're working with?

Comment: I managed to fix it based on your advice. It was due to convex not being set, as well as me applying a mesh collider to the prefab and not the object directly, thank you for the help.

Comment: Want to post your solution in an Answer below?